# How to make default checkbox checked in angular 6?

Tags: angular, checkbox

lanuage.component.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <mat-checkbox class="versionstyle" name="languageenabled"[(ngModel)]="languageObj.languageenabled">Enabled</mat-checkbox>
</form>
```

I want to make checkbox is checked by default in angular6 , i search in google and apply so many solution but it does not work.

Comment: Just set the `ngModel`'s value to true for the one you want to be default

Comment: No, more like `this.languageObj.languageenabled = true` for example. (And also, your  HTML shouldn't have the `this` bit in it)

Comment: Then it appears your `languageenabled` property has been typed as a string, which is an issue somewhere within your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="myModel"/>
```

OR

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="myModel" class="example-margin"/>
```

Supposed that `myModel = true;` in `component.ts`

In your case, try to init `this.languageObj.languageenabled = true` in `component.ts`

Answer (score 1):

`mat-checkbox` exposes one `@Input() checked: Boolean` property. You can do this in your code:

```
[checked]="languageObj.languageenabled"
```

Comment: Thanks Jai, but it gives error like argument type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string : blob'

Comment: @AmishaRana okay got this and glad you got your issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For Checked-checkbox

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <mat-checkbox 
      [checked]="true">Checked
    </mat-checkbox>
</form>
```

For Unchecked-checkbox

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <mat-checkbox 
      [checked]="false">Uncheked
    </mat-checkbox>
</form>
```