# Default checked checkbox not working in angular

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular8, checked

I tried almost all ways `checked`,`checked="true"`,`[checked]="true"` and tried different answers [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52094619/how-to-make-default-checkbox-checked-in-angular-6) on stackoverflow but not working for me

```
    <ng-template #content>

    <label class="switch">
        <input  type="checkbox" name="{{day.id}}"  ngModel required #{{day.id}}="ngModel"  [checked]="true"  checked="true">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #other_content>

    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{day.id}}" ngModel required #{{day.id}}="ngModel">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are registering form control together with `ngModel` and `name` attribute. How to mark ngModel for template driven forms, it can vary from `ngModel`, `[ngModel]` or `[(ngModel)]`. Your pick for what solution you need. Here you have marked with `ngModel` means that the form control has no value. Angular forms do not care about the `checked` attribute, but listens to what value the form control has!

You can overcome this by instead of using `ngModel`, use `[ngModel]` and capture a `true` value for that field, so for that field change:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="{{day.id}}" required #{{day.id}}="ngModel" [ngModel]="true">
```